# Using 'with sexp' on a type generates "Warning 4: this pattern-matching is fragile"

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, compiler-warnings, s-expression

I've just started using the `with sexp` syntax extension (described [here](https://github.com/janestreet/sexplib) and [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/data-serialization-with-s-expressions.html)) on my custom types.  However, I've noticed that when I do, I get the following warning about my type:

`Warning 4: this pattern-matching is fragile. It will remain exhaustive when constructors are added to type Sexplib.Type.t.`

I'm *assuming* this is because the sexp converters that are generated by the `with sexp` syntax only handle the type constructors defined for Sexp (`Sexp.List` and `Sexp.Atom`).

I generally try to fix any warnings in my compilation; is there a way to make the compiler happy here (short of having it suppress the warning entirely for all cases)?

EDIT: for markdown formatting.

Update: Providing example code from `hit.ml`.

```
open Core.Std
open Option.Monad_infix

open Battey.Kernel

type hit = (sentence * int) with sexp
```

Generates this warning:

`File "hit.ml", line 6, characters 5-27:
Warning 4: this pattern-matching is fragile.
It will remain exhaustive when constructors are added to type Sexplib.Type.t.`

Other info: I'm using version 4.02.3 of ocamlc (as installed via `opam`) on a macbook (Yosemite) and am using version 113.00.00 of `core` and `core_kernel`.  I'm also using `-w A` for my cflags.

Apologies for the delay in updating; the holidays kept me away from my laptop/internet connection.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: could you please provide your code ? (or just a subset that exhibits this behaviour)

Comment: Did you open `Core.Std`?

Comment: @ivg yep, I'm opening `Core.Std`.  I've added a code snippet.

Comment: @PierreG. I updated my question with an example of code that causes this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by using something like

```
match t with
| A -> 0
| B -> 1
| _ -> 2
```

This looks fine if `type t = A | B | C`. But when later a constructor D is added the _ will just match it and usually that is not what you want. Doesn't look like there is anything you can do but ignore the warning though.